# How to have kernel trace and Chromium trace beside each other?

Tags: linux-kernel, chromium, trace

Is there any method to instrument both kernel level and user level for Chromium in Linux (Ubuntu)? Chromium tracer just provides a call stack of functions in user level. Is it possible to have kernel level traces as well?

Thanks.